# How to change the dropdown value based on click of Previous/Next button in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular

i have a dropdown and Previous and Next Button. So here, either i can manually change the dropdown value or based on click of Previous and Next, the dropdown values to be changed.
I tried, i am able to get the previous and next index value but not able to bind that value inside index as the selected option. can anyone help me, where i am going wrong.

TS:

```
  public changeDropdown(value) {
    this.selectedDropdownValue = this.dropdownValue.findIndex(x => x.noteid === parseInt(value));
  }

  public previousNextValue(value) {
      let previousValue = this.selectedDropdownValue;
      previousValue = value ? ++previousValue : --previousValue
      this.changeDropdown(previousValue);
  }
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <select class="custom-select w-100" name="noteTypeId" (change)="changeDropdown($event.target.value)">
                <option value="" selected disabled>Select Note Details</option>
                <option *ngFor="let notesItem of dropdownValue" [value]="notesItem.noteid">
                    {{notesItem.dropdownsubject}}
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" (click)="previousNextValue(false)"
                    [disabled]="selectedDropdownValue==0"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
                        Previous</button> 
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary ml-1" type="button" (click)="previousNextValue(true)"
                    [disabled]="selectedDropdownValue+1==dropdownValue.length">Next <i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7xzt8d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do some changes in your code:

You need to set a value property on the select

```
[value]="selectedDropdownValue"
```

Right now you get the array index of the value you want to change to but your options have the value of the noteId

```
public changeDropdown(value) {
    const entry = this.dropdownValue.findIndex(x => x.noteId === parseInt(value));
    this.selectedDropdownValue = this.dropdownValue[entry].noteId;
}
```

After this change you have to modify your disabled logic on the buttons.

For the next button we need to get the noteId for the last item, that is:

```
[disabled]="selectedDropdownValue === dropdownValue[dropdownValue.length - 1].noteId"
```

And for the previous button:

```
[disabled]="selectedDropdownValue<=1"
```

To show your default (select) change your option to 0 (Or you could change the initial value of your selectedDropdownValue):

```
<option value="0" selected disabled>Select Note Details</option>
```

Our logic for the next and previous is not as simple as counting up and down because we need to support the noteIds and not the array index we need to modify the `previousNextValue` Method:

```
public previousNextValue(value) {
    let previousValue = this.selectedDropdownValue;
    if (previousValue === 0) {
        // 0 as selectedDropdownValue is our initial value ('Select Note Details') and has not yet an actual noteid as value, so we set the noteId from our first element
        this.selectedDropdownValue = this.dropdownValue[0].noteId
    } else {
        // If we already have a valid noteId as selectedDropdownValue we need to find it in the array and get the noteId from the next element
        const currentIndex = this.dropdownValue.findIndex(x => x.noteId === previousValue);
        this.selectedDropdownValue = this.dropdownValue[value ? currentIndex + 1 : currentIndex - 1].noteId
    }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkgu6n?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the response, when there is no value selected, how can i show the default option value as "Select Note".

Comment: Thanks, it is working as expected, i will vote and accept answer

Comment: i need your help on this, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1flp1i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Pascal, here if i have more data of dropdown values, it results in error and wont allow to move forward. Please help

Comment: @Bhrungarajni I updated the answer. Problem was that the previousNextValue calculation was based on the index and not on the noteIds that can be different